# Infinite solution in quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, quadratics

In my textbook it says that some quadratic equations can have infinite solutions. For example if $x^2-2x=x^2-3$ then rather than cancelling $x^2$ from both sides the book lets $x=\frac{1}{m}$ and then rearranges to get $1-2m=1-3m^2$ or $m(3m-2)=0$ therefore $m=0$ or $m=\frac{2}{3}$ giving $x=\infty$ or $\frac{3}{2}$. This is the first time I see this so I am just wondering if $\infty$ is actually a valid solution?

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the book please? It's useful to know what sources you're working from.

Comment: Your wording is a bit misleading - do you mean '$\textbf{infitely many}$ solutions' or 'can have $\textbf{infinity}$ as a solution'?

Comment: $x=\infty$ is not a valid solution: for $m= 0$ you have $x=\frac{1}{0}$ which is (in general) undefined.

Comment: If this is an elementary algebra textbook, the calculation seems highly suspect. But there is a sense where it makes sense to talk about common points at infinity, if you homogenize the polynomials and work in the projective plane.

Comment: I find it fascinating noone has mentioned the fact that $x^2-2x=x^2-3$ isn't even a quadratic equation (in fact, it's linear, for it rewrites to $2x-3=0$)

Comment: @vrugtehagel: mh, seen as a first degree equation, there is a single solution; seen as a quadratic equation, there must be two and one of them has escaped to infinity.

Comment: "Seen as a quadratic equation..." it's not though. Although there's a $x^2$ in there, it's total coefficient is $0$, thus, it cannot be regarded a quadratic equation. A quadratic equation is one of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ *with $a$ nonzero*

Comment: @vrugtehagel If you cancel out the $x^{2}$'s then it's linear, but the OP has provided an approach that transforms it to an equation that _is_ quadratic in $m$.

Comment: Consider  $y_1=(x-1)^2-1$ and $y_2=x^2-3$ you are trying to find the intersection of the two graphs. Both are just translations of $y=x^2$ importantly there are no stretches.  The graphs intersect at one place only.

Comment: @BillWallis yes, but the transformation may (and does, in this case) create new roots that don't necessarily satisfy the original equation. Take for example the "equation" $x=-3$. Square it; $x^2=9$, and voila! One has two solutions. It's just not how it works. Some transformations create new solutions and thus the solutions must be checked afterwards. Substitution with $x=\frac1m$ is one of those.

Comment: @vrugtehagel The injectivity of $x = \frac{1}{m}$ (other than at $x = 0$) would contradict your example, but I will admit that it is precisely the issue that $m$ _cannot_ be zero under this transformation that causes the problem here.

Comment: There are mathematical perspectives in which it makes sense to say that the two quadratics intersect more than once, and which do so by constructing a point or points at infinity to locate the 'missing' intersection(s) (user7530 gives the example of working over projective space) - the insight in your textbook can then be made rigorous. In some of these, the intersection of two quadratics (each of order two) should have $2\times 2=4$ points so you might be counting a point at which the curves touch as two (or more) solutions. But using loose infinities in elementary work can lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the real number line as being bent to a circle and glued together at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, yielding a single point called $\infty$ (i.e. you do *not* distinguish between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$). This is called compactification (in fact a particular one, it's not unique) and yields a set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ that even allows to do some "unusual" arithmetic such as $a/0=\infty$ and $a/\infty=0$ (for $a \neq 0$). So in this sense, $\infty$ is indeed a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \gg\lim_{x\to\infty}x\gg\lim_{x\to\infty}c$$
Here $c$ is some constant less than $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate response would be no.

There are many reasons for this, I'll propose just two:

Firstly, $m = 0$ with $x = \frac{1}{m}$ *has no solutions for $x$*. Division by zero is not allowed --- and, depending on your approach, $1/0$ could be *any number you want*. Just compute the limit from either direction to see at least two possible alternatives; from the positive side of $0$, $x/0$ approaches $+\infty$ but from the negative side of $0$, $x/0$ approaches $-\infty$.

Secondly, *any* polynomial can have a solution that is infinity in this case, if one abides by the proposed axioms of infinity ($\infty + c = \infty$, $k\times\infty = \infty$ for all $c, k \in \mathbb{R}$).

In higher levels of Mathematics it may be the case that you can have infinity as a solution, but I've always steered clear of it. Infinity does weird things!